# material ui button with styled-components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I was using this material ui button and it had a purple background

```
<Button
      component={Link}
      to={link}
      style={{
        background: '#6c74cc',
        borderRadius: 3,
        border: 0,
        color: 'white',
        height: 48,
        padding: '0 30px',
        width: 200,
      }}>
```

I tried changing it to a styled-component:

```
export const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  background: #6c74cc;
  border-radius: 3;
  border: 0;
  color: white;
  height: 48;
  padding: 0 30px;
  width: 200px;
`;
```

But it looks quite different. The background is white while the text is black. Even though I am applying the same styling. The width is also different. How can I fix this?

https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-frost-muv1s?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things to consider when using `material-ui`

1. [You'll need to separate the style properties by semi-colons `;`](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-component)
2. Even then, most styles are overridden by in-built `material-ui` classes because those classes have higher specificity. To overcome that, use the `&&` operator to apply the styles on the same specificity level.
3. Lastly, `background` needs to also be set on `:hover` to override the `material-ui` style

With these changes, your styled component would look like this:

```
export const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  && {
    background: #6c74cc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 0;
    color: white;
    height: 48px;
    padding: 0 30px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    &:hover {
      background: #6c74cc;
    }
  }
`;
```

And you can see it working in [this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-hooks-nkgkw?file=/src/App.js:138-405)

Comment: I don't think that's the only problem. Could you see the sandbox I added? Weird but the color on my localhost is different than on the sandbox, even though I literally copied the same part. Still, the widths are different than what I want (like <Button>)

Comment: @a125 Yes there were more things to look into, have a look at my updated answer and codesandbox link